# How to Include List numbers in the border of list items of a sortable menu items using jqueryUI

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, html5-canvas

Sorry if this has been asked earlier.

I'm making a sortable ordered list using `jqueryUI`. It is working fine but I've added the list items in border along with some padding. But the numbers are not included in the border, as they are outside of the border.

Is there a way which we can include the listing numbers inside the border of the list items.

Here is a screenshot: [image]

Is there any way to do this?
Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: move;
  width: 100%;
}
#sortable li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.list-group {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <ol id="sortable" class="list-group">
    <li>
      A Good MeaL
    </li>
    <li>
      Nonsense
    </li>
    <li>
      A Fine
    </li>
    <li>
      A Devoted Scientist
    </li>
    <li>
      A Rubbish Heap
    </li>
    <li>
      A Technical Improvement
    </li>
    <li>
      Blow Up an Airliner in Flight
    </li>
    <li>
      Burn a Heretic at the Stake
    </li>
    <li>
      A Short Circuit
    </li>
    <li>
      By this Ring, I Thee Wed
    </li>
    <li>
      A Baby
    </li>
    <li>
      Torture a Person in a Concentration Camp
    </li>
    <li>
      Love of Nature
    </li>
    <li>
      A Madman
    </li>
    <li>
      An Assembly Line
    </li>
    <li>
      Slavery
    </li>
    <li>
      A Mathematical Genius
    </li>
    <li>
      A Uniform
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this style to `ol`

```
list-style: decimal inside;
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  list-style: decimal inside;// Added this one
  text-align: left;
  cursor: move;
  width: 100%;
}
#sortable li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.list-group {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <ol id="sortable" class="list-group" type="1">
    <li class="alt">
      A Good MeaL
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      Nonsense
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      A Fine
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      A Devoted Scientist
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      A Rubbish Heap
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      A Technical Improvement
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      Blow Up an Airliner in Flight
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      Burn a Heretic at the Stake
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      A Short Circuit
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      By this Ring, I Thee Wed
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      A Baby
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      Torture a Person in a Concentration Camp
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      Love of Nature
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      A Madman
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      An Assembly Line
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      Slavery
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      A Mathematical Genius
    </li>
    <li class="alt">
      A Uniform
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Loved it. What is the browser support of this property?

Comment: from `ie 4` onward. Nothing more to say `:)` [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style.asp)

Comment: Rino Raj You just made my day. Thanks a lot brother. Loved your answer.

Comment: Always glad to help and hear those `"words"`.  `:)`